# delete only lines that contain specific pattern

Tags: unix, scripting, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a tab delimited file with many number of features. I want to delete least informative lines. To be specific I want to delete lines that all have question mark (?) in all the columns except the last which can have yes or a no. My file looks like

```
a   b   c   frequent
?   ?   ?   No
?   ?   1   Yes
1   ?   1   No
?   1   1   Yes
?   ?   ?   No
?   ?   ?   Yes
```

I want to delete columns that have

```
?   ?   ?   No
```

or

```
?   ?   ?   Yes
```

I can use

```
sed '/pattern/d' ./ file
```

I However how do I use it for multiple copies of ?. There can be hundreds of column so solutions such as

```
sed '/?  ?  ?  No/d' ./ file
```

and

```
sed '/?  ?  ?  Yes/d' ./ file
```

will not work. I want my output to look like

```
a   b   c   frequent
?   ?   1   Yes
1   ?   1   No
?   1   1   Yes
```

EDIT 1: For columns in a tab delimited file with first column as serial number and last column as space delimited class labels. I want to consider second to second to last rows and remove columns that have all question marks.

```
No  a   b   c   itemname
1   ?   ?   ?   frying pan
2   ?   ?   1   t-shirt
3   1   ?   1   microwave oven
10  ?   1   1   forks and knives
11  ?   ?   ?   gold
12  ?   ?   ?   chain
```

The wanted output is

```
No  a   b   c   itemname
2   ?   ?   1   t-shirt
3   1   ?   1   microwave oven
10  ?   1   1   forks and knives
```

Comment: Note that the last column contain spaces. For instance "microwave oven"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this to handle both cases in one step

```
 sed -r '/(\?\s+){3}(Yes|No)/d' ./file
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the number of `?` per line, you can just replace `{3}` with `+` if you want "*one or more*" or use `{3,}` if you want something like "*3 or more*", or you can use `{3,5}` for example if you want to say "*between 3 and 5*"

**EDIT2:**

This is a grep alternative

```
egrep -v '(\?\s+){3}(Yes|No)' ./fileToTest > outputFile
```

**Note**:

The reason `sed` wasn't working is because we need `extended regex` after checking sed's help I found it's the flag `-r`

Comment: Interestingly didn't work in my case. By the looks of it, it was the best solution I was looking for.

Comment: @lovedynasty I added an alternative answer because I couldn't make `sed` work too, I'll keep testing the `sed` alternative

Comment: Fixed the `sed` answer

Comment: How can I change this to a tab delimited file and escape first column (which is line number) and last column (which can be space delimited characters).  I tried 

    sed -r '/([0-9]) (\?\t+){3}([a-z])/d' file

But it did not work.

Comment: try this, sed -r '/(?:[0-9]+\t)(\?\t+){3}[a-z]+/d'

Comment: if you know the exact number of `?` and don't care about the words at the end you can just ignore them using `.*`, like `sed -r '/(?:[0-9]+\t)(\?\t+){3}.*/d'`

Comment: Yes, I know the number of ?. However, with your command, I get this error. sed: -e expression #1, char 26: Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: ok it worked after removing the `?:` also make sure that you use tabs, otherwise replace `\t` with `\s` or `\s+` depending on how many spaces exist between non space characters

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `?`

```
sed '/\? +\? +\? +Yes/d' file
```

Since your file seems to be space separated with multiple space, you need `+`

Or if you have `tab`

```
sed '/\?\t\?\t\?\tNo/d' file
```

---

An `awk` solution to delete lines that only have `?`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i!~"?") f=1} f {print;f=x}' file
```

Or using aragaers approach, print only lines with at least one `1`

```
awk '/1/ || NR==1' file
a   b   c   frequent
?   ?   1   Yes
?   ?   1   Yes
```

Comment: There can be more than three columns (infact hundreds). So, this wouldn't work- Plus it deletes all lines with No.

Answer (score 2):

Is it guaranteed that column contains either `?` or `1`? If yes, simply delete everything unless it contains at least one `1` (and is not a first line):

```
sed -n '1p; /1/p;' file
```

Comment: How can I escape the first column in this answer, as I have a tab delimited file with line numbers as fist column.

Comment: Something like "print only lines that have 1 after tab": `sed -n '1p; /\t1/p;' file`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` :

```
[ ~]$ cat test.txt 
a   b   c   frequent
?   ?   ?   No
?   ?   1   Yes
1   ?   1   No
?   1   1   Yes
?   ?   ?   No
?   ?   ?   Yes
[ ~]$ awk '!($0 ~ "?\\ *?\\ *?\\ *(Yes|No)"){print}' test.txt
a   b   c   frequent
?   ?   1   Yes
1   ?   1   No
?   1   1   Yes
[ ~]$
```

You could also use `egrep` like this :

```
[ ~]$ egrep  -v "\?\ *\?\ *\?\ *(Yes|No)" test.txt 
a   b   c   frequent
?   ?   1   Yes
1   ?   1   No
?   1   1   Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last update, you can modify the solution of @Jotne as follows:

```
NR==1 {
    p=NF-2
    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=p;i++) {
        if (!( $(i+1)=="?")) f=1
    }
}
f {
    print
    f=x
}
```